# i get ADB error when i run flutter app in real device

Tags: flutter

i get this error when i try to run my flutter app in my phone:
"Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install
adb:failed to install C:\xampp\htdocs\My project\untitled\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]
Error launching application on M2101K7AG."
the adb is installed in my pc correctly and this is the version of it :Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.1-9680074
Installed as C:\Users\elathir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe